# xtext: Generate Scala stubs from workflow

Tags: scala, xtext

Can I use Scala instead of xtend when developing a DSL using Xtext?

I want to use Scala to interact with Isabelle and limit the number of languages I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would actually have to exchange all generator fragments to generate native scala stubs so i recomment you generate java stubs and create and bind scala subclasses manually

```
code = {
    preferXtendStubs = false
    encoding = "UTF-8"
    fileHeader = "/*\n * generated by Xtext \${version}\n */"
}
```